# Inverse Image of Function Implies Continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $f$ be a function from a metric space $(X,d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}((-\infty, a])$ and $f^{-1}([a, \infty))$ are closed in $X$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

I am confused about how to go about this. I keep contradicting myself, and am not sure how to get going. My professor said to use the fact that any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a union of disjoint intervals. However, I am unfamiliar with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which definition of continuity are you using?

Comment: The usual definition? I haven't been introduced to others. I know that $f$ is continuous iff whever $E$ is an open subset in the codomain we have $f^{-1}(E)$ is open in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to assume that the space $X$ is metric, the claim holds for any topological space $X$. Indeed, to show that a map $f$ from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ is continuous, it suffices to fix a  subbase $\mathcal B$ of the space $Y$ and show that a set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ for each $U\in\mathcal B$. For our case we put

$$\mathcal B=\{(-\infty,a):a\in\Bbb R\}\cup \{(a,\infty):a\in\Bbb R\}.$$

Then for each real $a$ we have that a set $f^{-1}((-\infty,a))=X\setminus f^{-1}([a,\infty))$ is open as a complement of a closed set $f^{-1}([a,\infty))$. We can similarly show that a set $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is open.